# Why does NPM installs older version of specified node module?

Tags: npm, asp.net-core-2.0, vuetify.js

In my **asp.net core 2.0 + Vue** Project, I have **package.json** as shown in the image below.

whenever i do npm install, the older version of vuetify gets installed. i.e. even after specifying the minor release as **[^1.2.1]** ,the version installed is **[0.16.9]**.

(I have tried creating vue standalone application and installing Vuetify inside it. it properly installs the latest version)

What may be Causing this?
[image]

Comment: Is there a `package-lock.json` file? I think it's safe to delete and and re-run `npm i`. Or try clearing the cache.

Comment: Your `package-lock.json` file could have the older version and installs are based off this. I recommend you to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` before running `npm install` again.

Comment: I didn't had `package-lock.json` but i did had `npm-shrink wrap.json` , where in vuetify was locked at `0.16.9` . deleting that file and running npm install once again installed the latest version `1.2.3` Thank you :)